# Spring Security - disable security dynamically

Tags: java, security, properties, spring-security

How can I disable Spring Security dynamically? With the code below, my application requires authentication to access some pages, but I'd like to enable / disable that using property files. Any suggestions?

- Spring Security 4
- I know about [setting the security attribute to false in the http tag](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/) but that requires recompiling code, which is not sufficient for me.

  ```
  <sec:http>
      <sec:intercept-url pattern="/services/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
      <sec:intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

      <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
      <sec:http-basic />

      <sec:csrf disabled="true" /> 
  </sec:http>
  ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about using spel  http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.x/reference/html/el-access.html#el-access-web-beans

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the user and roles  being fetched from data base table.Customize some property file so when the server starts up it appropriately updates the db with required roles and the  user gets the roles as required.So you can by pass the already existing security.(not exactly by passing but granting the roles based on property file)

Note : you have to write a one time util class to parse the property file and update db which should happen on server start up.

Comment: Yep - user and roles come from the db. I don't really understand how adding some roles and users will turn the security on or off, or how dynamic (as in I can turn it on or off during runtime) it is, could you clarify, please?

Comment: The above proposed method will not turn on or off the spring security dynamically,but its like changing the roles in db as required based on the properties file.